# Where is Visible Changed Event gone in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events, panel

I want to have visibleChanged event of panel in asp.net(using VB.net) to shorten my code. But I cant find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Control.VisibleChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.windows.forms.control.visiblechanged.aspx) Event is only available for winform application. It is present in `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.

Comment: Did you mean its not available in webforms?

Comment: yes @vishal, it's not for webforms. As you can see from the documentation as well